# Reading Data from Firebase and displaying on a table using Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am following the tutorial by Mosh to create an online shop. My Firebase Realtime DB has the data about the products which I have previously implemented. Now, I want to display the information about those products in a table. The problem is that the title and price are not being displayed, however the edit button contains the link referring to the key of the product. It would be great if someone can help me with this issue. TIA

**#admin-products.component.html**

```
<p>
<a routerLink = "/admin/products/new" class="btn btn-primary"> Update Products</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let p of products$ | async">
            <td>{{ p.title }}</td>
            <td>{{ p.price }}</td>
            <td>
                <a [routerLink]="['/admin/products/',p.key]"> Edit</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**#admin-products.component.ts**

```
products$:any;

  constructor(private productService: ProductService) {
    this.products$= this.productService.getAll();
   }
```

**#product.service.ts**

```
getAll() {
  return this.db.list('/productlist').snapshotChanges();
}
```

Comment: what does this give you `console.log(this.products$);`

Comment: @PeterHaddad the answer given by Stratubas worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think (untested) that your problem is here:

```
<tr *ngFor="let p of products$ | async">
    <td>{{ p.title }}</td>
    <td>{{ p.price }}</td>
    <td>
        <a [routerLink]="['/admin/products/',p.key]"> Edit</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

There should be a `payload` intermediate property with a `val()` method, like this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let p of products$ | async">
    <td>{{ p.payload.val().title }}</td>
    <td>{{ p.payload.val().price }}</td>
    <td>
        <a [routerLink]="['/admin/products/',p.key]"> Edit</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```